# InvalidProtocolBufferException always thrown on BatchAnnotateImagesResponse.parseFrom()

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to use **Google Cloud Vision's API**. So far I have achieved to make the request succesfully and receive the desired data on a json format. The problem comes to parsing that response into a model class that I can use.

The **request**, **response** and **parsing** are made in the same method:

## Request:

```java
private static BatchAnnotateImagesResponse clientImageRequest(String contenidoImagen) {             
        BatchAnnotateImagesResponse sol = BatchAnnotateImagesResponse.getDefaultInstance();

        log.log(Level.FINEST, "Procesando la imagen del cliente");
        try {

            log.log(Level.FINE, "Creando conexion");
            URL serverUrl = new URL(TARGET_URL + API_KEY); //previously declared constants
            URLConnection urlConnection = serverUrl.openConnection();
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)urlConnection;

            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            httpConnection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
            httpConnection.setReadTimeout(60000);

            httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            log.log(Level.FINE, "Creando peticion");
            BufferedWriter httpRequestBodyWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(httpConnection.getOutputStream()));
            httpRequestBodyWriter.write(
                    "{\"requests\": [{ \"features\": [ { \"maxResults\": 10, \"type\": \"WEB_DETECTION\" } ], \"image\": { \"content\": \""+contenidoImagen+"\" } } ] }");
            httpRequestBodyWriter.close();

            log.log(Level.INFO, "BufferedWriter de la peticion cerrado correctamente");
```

As I said this part goes smoothly.

---

## Response:

```java
log.log(Level.FINE, "Obteniendo la respuesta");
            InputStream respuesta = httpConnection.getInputStream();

            if (respuesta == null) {
                log.log(Level.SEVERE, "No hay InputStream");
                throw new NullPointerException("InputStream nulo");
            }else {
                log.log(Level.FINEST, "La respuesta se ha recibido correctamente");

                //sol = BatchAnnotateImagesResponse.parseFrom(respuesta);  this throws IOException

                Scanner httpResponseScanner = new Scanner (respuesta);
                StringBuilder resp = new StringBuilder("");
                while (httpResponseScanner.hasNext()) {
                    String line = httpResponseScanner.nextLine();
                    resp.append(line);
                    log.log(Level.INFO, line);

                    if(httpResponseScanner.hasNext()) {
                        resp.append("\n");
                    }
                }
                log.log(Level.INFO, "Respuesta al completo: \n"+resp.toString());
                httpResponseScanner.close();
                log.log(Level.FINE, "Scanner cerrado correctamente");
```

As you can see in the logs, I print `resp.toString()`, and it returns the correspondent body response of the image I introduce. For example, a building (I had to shorten it due to SOF max body characters):

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: {
[INFO] GCLOUD:   "responses": [
[INFO] GCLOUD:     {
[INFO] GCLOUD:       "webDetection": {
[INFO] GCLOUD:         "webEntities": [
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "url": "http://passionbythetravel.com/top-10-tallest-buildings-in-spain/",
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "pageTitle": "Top 10 Tallest Buildings in Spain » Passion by the Travel",
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "partialMatchingImages": [
[INFO] GCLOUD:               {
[INFO] GCLOUD:                 "url": "http://passionbythetravel.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Torre-Sevilla.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:               }
[INFO] GCLOUD:             ]
[INFO] GCLOUD:           },
[INFO] GCLOUD:           {
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "url": "https://votefrankharris.com/image/savanaspringarn",
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "pageTitle": "Savanaspringarn - Vote Frank Harris",
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "partialMatchingImages": [
[INFO] GCLOUD:               {
[INFO] GCLOUD:                 "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg/274px-Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:               }
[INFO] GCLOUD:             ]
[INFO] GCLOUD:           },
[INFO] GCLOUD:           {
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "url": "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torre_Sevilla",
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "pageTitle": "Torre \u003cb\u003eSevilla\u003c/b\u003e - Wikipedia, la enciclopedia libre",
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "fullMatchingImages": [
[INFO] GCLOUD:               {
[INFO] GCLOUD:                 "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg/1200px-Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:               },
[INFO] GCLOUD:               {
[INFO] GCLOUD:                 "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg/250px-Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:               },
[INFO] GCLOUD:               {
[INFO] GCLOUD:                 "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:               }
[INFO] GCLOUD:             ]
[INFO] GCLOUD:           },
[INFO] GCLOUD:           {
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "url": "https://moovitapp.com/index/en/public_transit-Torre_Sevilla-Sevilla-site_14527821-3802",
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "pageTitle": "How to get to Torre \u003cb\u003eSevilla\u003c/b\u003e in \u003cb\u003eSevilla\u003c/b\u003e by Bus, Train or Metro | Moovit",
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "partialMatchingImages": [
[INFO] GCLOUD:               {
[INFO] GCLOUD:                 "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg/274px-Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:               }
[INFO] GCLOUD:             ]
[INFO] GCLOUD:           },
[INFO] GCLOUD:           {
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "url": "https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivo:Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg",
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "pageTitle": "Archivo:Torre \u003cb\u003eSevilla\u003c/b\u003e 2017.jpg - Wikipedia, la enciclopedia libre",
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "fullMatchingImages": [
[INFO] GCLOUD:               {
[INFO] GCLOUD:                 "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg/1200px-Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:               },
[INFO] GCLOUD:               {
[INFO] GCLOUD:                 "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg/321px-Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:               },
[INFO] GCLOUD:               {
[INFO] GCLOUD:                 "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg/513px-Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:               },
[INFO] GCLOUD:               {
[INFO] GCLOUD:                 "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:               },
[INFO] GCLOUD:               {
[INFO] GCLOUD:                 "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg/401px-Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:               },
[INFO] GCLOUD:               {
[INFO] GCLOUD:                 "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg/160px-Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:               },
[INFO] GCLOUD:               {
[INFO] GCLOUD:                 "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg/684px-Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:               }
[INFO] GCLOUD:             ]
[INFO] GCLOUD:           },
[INFO] GCLOUD:           {
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "url": "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivo:Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg",
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "pageTitle": "Archivo:Torre \u003cb\u003eSevilla\u003c/b\u003e 2017.jpg - Wikipedia, la enciclopedia libre",
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "fullMatchingImages": [
[INFO] GCLOUD:               {
[INFO] GCLOUD:                 "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg/1200px-Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:               },
[INFO] GCLOUD:               {
[INFO] GCLOUD:                 "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg/321px-Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:               },
[INFO] GCLOUD:               {
[INFO] GCLOUD:                 "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg/513px-Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:               },
[INFO] GCLOUD:               {
[INFO] GCLOUD:                 "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:               },
[INFO] GCLOUD:               {
[INFO] GCLOUD:                 "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg/401px-Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:               },
[INFO] GCLOUD:               {
[INFO] GCLOUD:                 "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg/160px-Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:               },
[INFO] GCLOUD:               {
[INFO] GCLOUD:                 "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg/684px-Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:               }
[INFO] GCLOUD:             ]
[INFO] GCLOUD:           },
[INFO] GCLOUD:           {
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "url": "https://moovitapp.com/index/es/transporte_p%C3%BAblico-Torre_Sevilla-Sevilla-site_14527821-3802",
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "pageTitle": "Cómo llegar a Torre \u003cb\u003eSevilla\u003c/b\u003e en \u003cb\u003eSevilla\u003c/b\u003e en Autobús, Tren o Metro ...",
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "partialMatchingImages": [
[INFO] GCLOUD:               {
[INFO] GCLOUD:                 "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg/274px-Torre_Sevilla_2017.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:               }
[INFO] GCLOUD:             ]
[INFO] GCLOUD:           },
[INFO] GCLOUD:           {
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "url": "https://www.instantoffices.com/es/es/alquiler-de-oficinas/sevilla/estadio-ol%C3%ADmpico-de-la-cartuja-34910",
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "pageTitle": "Oficinas: Estadio Olímpico de la Cartuja, \u003cb\u003eSeville\u003c/b\u003e, 41092 | Oficinas ...",
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "fullMatchingImages": [
[INFO] GCLOUD:               {
[INFO] GCLOUD:                 "url": "https://content.instantoffices.com/sc/Prod/images/centres/212width/50161/50161-377239.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:               }
[INFO] GCLOUD:             ]
[INFO] GCLOUD:           },
[INFO] GCLOUD:           {
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "url": "https://www.instantoffices.com/es/es/alquiler-de-oficinas/sevilla/paseo-de-las-delicias-12434",
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "pageTitle": "Oficinas: Paseo de las Delicias, \u003cb\u003eSeville\u003c/b\u003e, 41001 | Oficinas ...",
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "fullMatchingImages": [
[INFO] GCLOUD:               {
[INFO] GCLOUD:                 "url": "https://content.instantoffices.com/sc/Prod/images/centres/212width/50161/50161-377239.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:               }
[INFO] GCLOUD:             ]
[INFO] GCLOUD:           }
[INFO] GCLOUD:         ],
[INFO] GCLOUD:         "visuallySimilarImages": [
[INFO] GCLOUD:           {
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "url": "https://sevillasecreta.co/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Torre_Sevilla_abril_2015.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:           },
[INFO] GCLOUD:           {
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "url": "https://archivos.wikanda.es/sevillapedia/thumb/Torre_Cajasol_%28Sevilla%29.jpg/280px-Torre_Cajasol_%28Sevilla%29.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:           },
[INFO] GCLOUD:           {
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "url": "https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/09/49/9f/7b/cajasol-tower.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:           },
[INFO] GCLOUD:           {
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "url": "https://m.eldiario.es/andalucia/Torre-Sevilla_EDIIMA20160217_0512_18.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:           },
[INFO] GCLOUD:           {
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "url": "https://www.torre-sevilla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/imagen_3.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:           },
[INFO] GCLOUD:           {
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "url": "http://i.imgur.com/PSpQZER.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:           },
[INFO] GCLOUD:           {
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "url": "https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0a/a1/a3/e3/cajasol-tower.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:           },
[INFO] GCLOUD:           {
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "url": "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-D0B9SCQUh2o/Vak22borOWI/AAAAAAAADn4/H9YFAkUbvAk/s1600/esp179.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:           },
[INFO] GCLOUD:           {
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "url": "https://static1-sevilla.abc.es/Media/201501/30/torre-pelli-sevilla--644x362.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:           },
[INFO] GCLOUD:           {
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "url": "http://i.imgur.com/GSdKmVp.jpg"
[INFO] GCLOUD:           }
[INFO] GCLOUD:         ],
[INFO] GCLOUD:         "bestGuessLabels": [
[INFO] GCLOUD:           {
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "label": "pintalabios sevilla",
[INFO] GCLOUD:             "languageCode": "es"
[INFO] GCLOUD:           }
[INFO] GCLOUD:         ]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       }
[INFO] GCLOUD:     }
[INFO] GCLOUD:   ]
[INFO] GCLOUD: }
```

---

## Parsing:

```java
                log.log(Level.FINE, "Convirtiendo string de respuesta a modelo");
                sol = BatchAnnotateImagesResponse.parseFrom(ByteBuffer.wrap(resp.toString().getBytes()));//The code explodes here

            }

        }catch(MalformedURLException e1) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "La URL se ha formado incorrectamente"+ Arrays.toString(e1.getStackTrace()));
        }catch(IOException e2) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Problema en la lectura/escritura de los datos\n"+e2.toString()+"\n"+Arrays.toString(e2.getStackTrace()));
        }catch(Exception e3) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Algo ha pasado durante el procesamiento de la imagen: "+ Arrays.toString(e3.getStackTrace()));
        }

        return sol;

    }
```

---

### Errors:

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: SEVERE: Problema en la lectura/escritura de los datos
[INFO] GCLOUD: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.
[INFO] GCLOUD: [com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidEndTag(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:106), com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream$ArrayDecoder.checkLastTagWas(CodedInputStream.java:635), com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream$ArrayDecoder.readGroup(CodedInputStream.java:834), com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Builder.mergeFieldFrom(UnknownFieldSet.java:548), com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.parseUnknownField(GeneratedMessageV3.java:320), com.google.cloud.vision.v1.BatchAnnotateImagesResponse.<init>(BatchAnnotateImagesResponse.java:89), com.google.cloud.vision.v1.BatchAnnotateImagesResponse.<init>(BatchAnnotateImagesResponse.java:30), com.google.cloud.vision.v1.BatchAnnotateImagesResponse$1.parsePartialFrom(BatchAnnotateImagesResponse.java:934), com.google.cloud.vision.v1.BatchAnnotateImagesResponse$1.parsePartialFrom(BatchAnnotateImagesResponse.java:928), com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:134), com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:149), com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:48), com.google.cloud.vision.v1.BatchAnnotateImagesResponse.parseFrom(BatchAnnotateImagesResponse.java:257), aiss.controller.WebDetectionController.clientImageRequest(WebDetectionController.java:103), aiss.controller.WebDetectionController.imageToModel(WebDetectionController.java:123), org.apache.jsp.web_002ddetection_jsp._jspService(web_002ddetection_jsp.java:129), org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70), javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790), org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476), org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386), org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330), com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.PrivilegedJspServlet.access$101(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:21), com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.PrivilegedJspServlet$2.run(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:75), java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method), com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.PrivilegedJspServlet.service(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:71), javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790), org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsyncServlet.service(ServletHolder.java:1395), org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:755), org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1617), com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63), org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604), com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366), com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349), com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116), org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604), com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.java:28), org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604), org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545), org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143), org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:608), org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127), org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235), org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1610), org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233), org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1300), org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188), org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485), org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1580), org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186), org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1215), com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.doScope(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94), org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141), org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:220), org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:79), aiss.ImageServlet.doGet(ImageServlet.java:65), aiss.ImageServlet.doPost(ImageServlet.java:91), javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707), javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790), org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsyncServlet.service(ServletHolder.java:1395), org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:755), org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1617), com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134), org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604), com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34), org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604), com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63), org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604), com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48), org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604), com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:123), org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604), com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366), com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349), com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116), org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604), com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.java:28), org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1596), org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545), org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143), org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:566), org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127), org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235), org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1610), org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233), org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1300), org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188), org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485), org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1580), org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186), org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1215), com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.doScope(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94), org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141), org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127), com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:610), org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127), org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500), org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383), org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547), org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375), org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273), org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311), org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103), org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117), org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806), org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938), java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)]
```

I have tried `parseFrom()` in all its variants but it **always** throws `InvalidProtocolBufferException` and I can't pass through it. What's wrong?

Comment: Why are you using Protocol Buffers for this? It seems to return JSON. Why not read the JSON with a library like GSON?

Comment: @TomCools that's the google vision api library, I'd prefer not to create a class when they provide the official one to read this.

Comment: Have you tried reading the Inputstream (response) as a byte array instead of String? 
Now you read it as a string, then use the ByteWrapper. Why not read a byte[] from the inputstream directly? Even better, use their client, not your own HTTP Client.

See example (ImageAnnotatorClient in that one).
https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries#client-libraries-install-java

Comment: @TomCools Still throwing it: I have tried what you have said like this                           sol = BatchAnnotateImagesResponse.parseFrom(ByteString.copyFrom(IOUtils.toByteArray(respuesta)));

Comment: @TomCools Due to the lack of time and the persistence of the error I opted to use your inital advice and create new java classes with jsonchema2pojo, and parse it with GSON. Thanks, it finally works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tom Cools said in the comments, the fastest (maybe not the best) way to solve this is to use specific libraries to read JSON instead of Protocol Buffers that are used on the Client Library of Vision's API.

I used [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to generate Java classes using the `resp.toString()` I showed on the question to crete them.

As a last step I used Gson to create an instance of the main class generated in jsonchema2pojo:

```java
Gson json = new Gson();
VisionResponse imagenes = json.fromJson(contenido, VisionResponse.class);
```

I would have liked to use the client library of the API, but this does its job.